# Echarts gantt: connect subtask to task

Tags: echarts

How to made a gantt chart with connected task/subtask and move them according to this relation?

I'm unable to find an example or some code about that.

EDIT: for example this gantt example:

https://echarts.apache.org/v4/examples/en/editor.html?c=custom-gantt-flight

How to connect one block with another with a line?